# Intranet website with Joomla?

Tags: content-management-system, joomla, webserver, xampp, portal

my company wants to set up a small intranet portal on LAN. We are about 100 users at max. I am thinking about Joomla on a windows server environment with XAMPP.

Just to be safe, is XAMPP efficient for serving about 50 to 100 users ? Does it have some connection limits ? Also how about using it as a webserver for a small intranet portal.

Have your say guys.

Comment: ive been tasked with doing something similar. spent the last 3 hrs looking around doing research and was JUST thinking on using wamp with joomla lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAMPP is "just" a collection of established applications for serving web pages. The underlaying apache can handle far more that the expected 100 users.

I haven't tried it yet, but think that maybe even the out-of-the-box configuration might be sufficient - if not you can always modify the underlaying Apache and/or MySQL database according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks perdian. I read that XAMPP is only for local testing environment & small companies. What do you say about the XAMPP & Joomla configuration as an intranet portal. Would it be able to accomodate round about 100 users ?

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP is just a handy single-click installer for Apache/MySQL/PHP which is all you need to run Joomla. This stack powers some of the largest websites on the net, so I don't think you'll run into any problems there. The specs of the server are what you should be most concerned about, but any low-range server should be able to handle that capacity without blinking.

Just be aware that the default settings used by XAMPP are specifically designed for developers working on their own local machines: there's no root password for MySQL, permissions are very relaxed, etc. Take some time to go through the config after you set it up.

Comment: Thanks nickf. Yep, XAMPP is really attractive because of all those features, really easy to set up and all. I will be running it on a mid level server machine. It's just once I used IIS on an XP machine and ran into max. no of concurrent connections issue =).

And thanks for the config tip =)

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at WAMP, depending on your requirements. Similar sort of thing but with the same issues that nickf stated.

Comment: Thank you, will look into it Jeepstone.