# What are the security measures I need to follow if I implement website in intranet?

Tags: php, intranet

Like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298530/intranet-website-with-joomla)   only but not in joomla and less than 10 users.We are going to give the demo of our web application on intranet and also we may implement in intranet only.So the concern is

1. The source code and database needs to be secure(i.e.Not easily readable by clients)
2. What are the security measures I need to follow in this situation?

Hint:we are going to implement on the windows server with xampp only.

Question 2:
I am not very well known to configure how to implement intranet site.What are the configuration I need to change in xampp?

Comment: What 'web application' are you talking about? A CRM? The source code is hosted on your server, if you're not opening holes in your code, it's safe enough (depending on your 'web application')

Comment: Like CRM only?We are going to host in the client server.At that time only i need to do some security measures and how do I do?

Answer (score 0):

PHP stored as a plain text on the server.
If you are going to store it on your client's server, then I'm afraid you can't really hide the code.

You can make it harder to read (obfuscate), using some software as described here: [How To Encrypt The Source Code Of PHP Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540486/how-to-encrypt-the-source-code-of-php-files)